# Where in this matlab code am I messing up?

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to write a code that 'grades' NFL receivers based on stats. It is a relatively simple program that i am making for a class project, and can probably get away with the error i am getting in Matlab (It is not running past the while loop. Basically, it displays the YPC but stops once it hits the while loop). However, I would love to have a working code. Please point out where I am making the mistake! Thank you

```
yards = input('Yards per game/season: ');
rec = input('Receptions per game/season: ');
long = input('Longest reception per game/season: ');
TD = input('Touchdowns per game/season: ');

YPC = (yards/rec);
display('Average Yards per Catch (YPC): ');
display(YPC);

grade = 0;

while YPC >= 1 
    if YPC >= 5.7 %NFL Average YPC
        grade = grade + 50; %Gives Reciever a 50 baseline rating if above average YPC
    else 
        grade = grade + 25; %Gives Reciever a 25 baseline rating if below average YPC

        if long >= 67.4 %NFL Average Longest Reception 
            grade = grade + (long/8); %Adds the longest reception divided by 8 to the grade if above average Long
        else 
            grade = grade - (long/16); %Subtracts the longest reception in 16 games from the grade if below average Long

            if TD >= 7.75 %NFL Average TD/Recievers
                grade = grade + ((TD * 10)/16); %Adds the number of touchdowns times 10, divided by 16 games if above average TDs
            else
                grade = grade + ((TD * 7)/16); %Adds the number of touchdows times 7, divided by 16 games if below average TDs
            end
        end
    end
end

display(grade);
```

Comment: YPC never changes inside the while, so once in it will never exit. Maybe you want to move the input commands inside the while loop in order to ask for new inputs.

Comment: If you get an error or warning, always include it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
YPC = 2;

while YPC >= 1 

    yards = input('Yards per game/season: ');
    rec = input('Receptions per game/season: ');
    long = input('Longest reception per game/season: ');
    TD = input('Touchdowns per game/season: ');

    YPC = (yards/rec);
    display('Average Yards per Catch (YPC): ');
    display(YPC);

    grade = 0;

    if YPC >= 5.7 %NFL Average YPC
        grade = grade + 50; %Gives Reciever a 50 baseline rating if above average YPC
    else 
        grade = grade + 25; %Gives Reciever a 25 baseline rating if below average YPC

        if long >= 67.4 %NFL Average Longest Reception 
            grade = grade + (long/8); %Adds the longest reception divided by 8 to the grade if above average Long
        else 
            grade = grade - (long/16); %Subtracts the longest reception in 16 games from the grade if below average Long

            if TD >= 7.75 %NFL Average TD/Recievers
                grade = grade + ((TD * 10)/16); %Adds the number of touchdowns times 10, divided by 16 games if above average TDs
            else
                grade = grade + ((TD * 7)/16); %Adds the number of touchdows times 7, divided by 16 games if below average TDs
            end
        end
    end
    display(grade);
end
```

This will let you calculate a new grade for new input values. New values will be asked at the start of a loop, to exit just give yards per game a value of 0.